# Invalid request (Unexpected EOF) - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tendo um problema usando o Laravel 5.4, do nada o site parou de funcionar (localmente) e dá esse erro no server (cmd) e o site não carrega. No console do navegador aparece o erro 500 ao carregar localhost.

```
No CMD aparece Invalid request (Unexpected EOF) conforme abaixo:
$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Tue Jun 27 09:37:02 2017] 127.0.0.1:56664 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Tue Jun 27 09:37:49 2017] 127.0.0.1:56685 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Tue Jun 27 09:39:29 2017] 127.0.0.1:56700 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Tue Jun 27 09:39:48 2017] 127.0.0.1:56680 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
[Tue Jun 27 09:39:48 2017] 127.0.0.1:56681 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
```

No log do Apache e do PHP aparece erro de memória, mas já aumentei pra 2048 e continua o erro. Testei o mesmo site no meu notebook, e lá funciona normal.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in D:\wamp64\www\Vandaflex2018\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 748
```

Comment: Qual foi a ultima alteração que você fez no código!?

Comment: pois é, já olhei as ultimas alterações e inclusive desativei elas, mas continua dando o erro.